# Jquery Autocomplete minChars

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I would like to change the value in minChars depending on a select value ?
I tried :

```
    var nbCharIso = 4;

    $j('#pays').change(function() {
      var isoPays = $j('select.pays option:selected').val();
      nbCharIso = (isoPays == 'Canada') ? 3 : nbCharIso; 
      alert(nbCharIso);
    });

    $j("#cp").autocomplete('codepostal.inc.php', {
        delay: 100,
        cacheLength: 0,
        //minChars: 4,
        minChars: nbCharIso,
        max: 100,
        width: 320,
        scrollHeight: 160,
        multiple: false,
        matchContains: true,
        formatItem: formatItem,
        formatResult: formatResult,
        extraParams: {
            country: function() { return $j('select.pays option:selected').val(); } 
        }
    }).result(function(e, item) {
        // foo
    });
```

But this doesn't work !
How can I change dynamically the minChars value in the autocomplete function ?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.autocomplete` is only being called once - when the form is loaded.  At the time it is called the value of nbCharIso is 4.

```
//var nbCharIso = 4; // comment this out or delete it
setupAutocomplete(4); // add this

$j('#pays').change(function() {
  var isoPays = $j('select.pays option:selected').val();
  var nbCharIso = (isoPays == 'Canada') ? 3 : 4; 
  //alert(nbCharIso);
  setupAutocomplete(nbCharIso); // add this
});

// wrap .autocomplete in a function so we can call it whenever we want
function setupAutocomplete(nbCharIso) {
$j("#cp").autocomplete('codepostal.inc.php', {
    delay: 100,
    cacheLength: 0,
    //minChars: 4,
    minChars: nbCharIso,
    max: 100,
    width: 320,
    scrollHeight: 160,
    multiple: false,
    matchContains: true,
    formatItem: formatItem,
    formatResult: formatResult,
    extraParams: {
        country: function() { return $j('select.pays option:selected').val(); } 
    }
}).result(function(e, item) {
    // foo
});

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? Won't calling the autocomplete method recreate the "autocomplete module" everytime? I think it's a better option to only modify the option.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like :

```
$j('#pays').change(function() {
      var isoPays = $j('select.pays option:selected').val();
      nbCharIso = (isoPays == 'Canada') ? 3 : nbCharIso; 

      $j("#cp").autocomplete( "option", "minChars", nbCharIso );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work as the setOptions method on the autocomplete plugin allows you to change the options after it has been setup:

```
$j('#pays').change(function() {
  var isoPays = $j('select.pays option:selected').val();
  nbCharIso = (isoPays == 'Canada') ? 3 : nbCharIso; 
  $j("#cp").setOptions({minChars: nbCharIso}); // <----- This will set the minChars value
  alert(nbCharIso);
});
```

Comment: @Chris np. Also, if you're using the latest version of autocomplete from jquery UI you can do - `$j("#cp").autocomplete("option", {minChars: nbCharIso});`. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it worked ;)

Comment: well in fact it's not working ;-( I didn't reload my page !!! I'm using the autocomplete from bassistance.de and not from Jquery UI !

Comment: The setOptions version should work then according to the [API](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/setOptions#options). Although I would recommend upgrading to use the jquery UI version as that is still being developed.